# DynamoDBMappingException no HASH key for GSI

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

This error that Dynamo throws is extremely vague but there is a way to narrow down the issue quickly. The code that throws this error can be found at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapperTableModel.java

Which is currently the only google search result for "no HASH key for GSI" which is why I've been inspired to create this post.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the most important code from the DynamoDB Java Library:

```
for (final DynamoDBMapperFieldModel<T,Object> field : fields.values()) {
                for (final String indexName : field.globalSecondaryIndexNames(RANGE)) {
                    final GlobalSecondaryIndex gsi = map.get(indexName);
                    if (gsi == null) {
                        throw new DynamoDBMappingException(
                            targetType.getSimpleName() + "[" + field.name() + "]; no HASH key for GSI " + indexName
                        );
                    }
                    gsi.withKeySchema(new KeySchemaElement(field.name(), RANGE));
                }
}
```

Notice the call to `final GlobalSecondaryIndex gsi = map.get(indexName);`. DynamoDB is attempting to use the name of the index that you've defined in your annotation to query a map containing values for that object and it comes up with null. A null is always the response from a java map when a value doesn't exist in the map but you've asked for it anyways.

This should clue us in. The `indexName` entry in the map of values has no mapping or no value associated with it. That must mean the `indexName` is wrong in either the table's declaration of the GlobalSecondaryIndex's index name or the annotation is wrong in the DynamoDBTable class where the GSI is annotated with `DynamoDBIndexHashKey`.

For me personally there was an extremely small discrepancy: `userId-Index` was defined in my `CreateTable` request but the field was annotated `userId-index`. Note the different in casing in `Index`.

So to sum up - if you're receiving this error - double, triple, and quadruple check all your annotations related to the index name.